# angular fontawesome social icons issue

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I have done the `npm install` for font-awesome icons in my angular application, and my `package.json` contains:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4"
```

And in my `app.module.ts`,  I have imported font-awesome:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
```

And in my component,

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Now when I use,   `<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>`, in my component html, I could able to successfully display the coffee cup icon. Now I need to display social icons like
`facebook`, `instagram` and `twitter`,  but when I trying to `<fa-icon [icon]="faFaceBook"></fa-icon>`, etc no icons are coming. Can any one provide me correct text to use these social icons  in [icon]= ? for `<fa-icon [icon]="?"></fa-icon>`

Comment: yes solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution:

```
npm add  @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

in component:

```
import { faTwitter,  faFacebookF, faInstagramSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

  faFacebook = faFacebookF;
  faInstagram = faInstagramSquare;
  faTwitter = faTwitter;


                 <li>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faFacebook"></fa-icon>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faInstagram"></fa-icon>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faTwitter"></fa-icon>
                </li>
```